# WOT convergence implies norm-boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I'm trying to prove that, on a Hilbert space $H$, convergence of a sequence of bounded operators $a_n$ to $a$ w.r.t. the weak operator topology (i.e. $\langle a_n x ,y \rangle \to \langle ax,y \rangle$ for all $x,y \in H$) implies that $a_n$ is norm-bounded. I have managed to prove the analogous statement for the strong operator topology using the Uniform Boundedness Principle, but I can't quite get it to work in the weak case. Could someone provide a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix $x$. Consider the linear functionals $f_x:y\longmapsto \overline{\langle a_nx,y\rangle}$. Because the sequence of numbers $\{\langle a_nx,y\rangle\}$ is convergent, it is bounded. That is,
$$\tag1
\sup_n|f_x(y)|=\sup_n|\langle a_nx,y\rangle|<\infty. 
$$
By the [Uniform Boundedness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), we get that
$$\tag2
\sup_n\|a_nx\|=\sup_n\sup_{\|y\|=1}|\langle a_nx,y\rangle|<\infty.
$$
As $(2)$ holds for all $x$, applying the UBP again we get
$$
\sup_n\|a_n\|<\infty
$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Though I guess you need to put a conjugate in the first line, to make the functional really linear, instead of conjugate-linear.

Comment: Indeed. Or I could say they are conjugate-linear ;)