# Operators act on a point to weak convergence to a operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence

$H$ is a Hilbert space, $T_n$ is a family of bounded linear operators, satisfies:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle T_nx,y\rangle$ exist for any $x,y\in H$.
Proof that exist a bounded linear operator $T$ satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle T_nx,y\rangle=\langle Tx,y \rangle$

I think the condition is a bit weak, generally speaking, we use the property of weak convergence by acting with functional to get strong convergence. But in this situation, even $ T_n x$ is weak convergence, how do we study $T$?

I tried to proof $\sup_{n}\Vert T_n\Vert$ exist by uniform bounded them, but later I gave a counter-example: $T_n(f)=f(x)\sqrt{n}sin(nx)$ on the space $L^2([0,1])$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628832/wot-convergence-implies-norm-boundedness

Comment: Your sequence $\{T_n\}$ does not converge. What happens is that a **subnet** converges. But, not being a sequence, the argument with the Uniform Boundedness Principle does not work (because the key is that a convergent sequence of numbers is bounded).